# How can find data traffic load between two servers?

Tags: network

I am backup admin. When I am running backup I am getting backup failure messages with status Socket Open and close errors. Backup is completing when less backup jobs are running.

I was ran SAS tool (https://www.appneta.com/sas/411/) and generate the report which was showing 63% to 90 % data loss.

We also increase BW between server and switch by teaming and enabling LACP. but still it is showing max 1 GBPS transfer rate on windows performance monitor. Please check the screenshot for network architecture:

[image: NETWORK DIAGRAM]

My questions are:

- What are the possible reasons for the same?
- Is there any other way by which we can find out the data traffic load on the network?
- How can we find out how much data is sending and receiving on the backup server from the network?

Comment: If you don't provide details to the network and the workload, how are we supposed to tell you what's wrong? Also, when there's only a single flow between two nodes LACP is no use.

Comment: Which details are needed? If possible, I will provide the details.

Comment: Well, a network diagram, hardware types, configurations of the relevant switch and router porits for a start.

Comment: See the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, and edit your question to include the necessary information. Remember that server/host configurations are off-topic here, as are product or resource recommendations. We can help with the network and on-topic network devices, but server and host questions can be asked on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the possible reasons for the same?

Your network might just be severely congested or there's something wrong with the port configurations or the general design.

> Is there any other way by which we can find out the data traffic load on the network?

The switches are likely to provide some information on that, e.g. `show interface port-utilization`.

> How can we find out how much data is sending and receiving on the backup server from the network?

This is what you see in Task Manager. You can get a more detailed view in Resource Monitor.

Port aggregation/LAG will only be able to do so much. Since a single flow will always use the same port combination LAG can't increase that bandwidth. It only helps avoiding aggregation bottlenecks. To increase the bandwidth between two nodes you *must increase the bandwidth* or use some kind of multilink load balancing, depending on the software in use.

Comment: Thanks Zac for the answer. We have already update BW from 1 GBPS to 4 GBPS. but resource monitor is still showing maximum utilization of 1 GBPS. So we want to find the deta transfer rete on the server. Is there any network tool which can generate report data flow and network utilization for 24 hr.

Comment: Yes, as stated LAG is no use when running only a single flow. For monitoring you might want to take a look at sFlow.